# class.getResource returns null from test resources

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have a class `Utils.scala` which contains this function:

```
object Utils {
    def getQueryFromFile(fileName: String): String = {
        if (fileName != null) {
            try {
                val path = getClass.getResourceAsStream(s"/$fileName.sql")
                Source.fromInputStream(path).getLines.mkString
            }
            catch {
                case _: NullPointerException => throw new FileNotFoundException(s"queryDefinition: $fileName Does not exist")
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new InvalidFileInputException(s"FileInput.read: file name is null")
        }
    }
}
```

I have two sql queries inside files present in `src/main/resources`. When I run this method from an `Object` that contains the `main()` method (from `src/main/scala`), it works fine, but when I try to run it through test cases (`ScalaTest`), it fails. It throws me this error:

```
queryDefinition: a.sql Does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: queryDefinition: COUNT_CHECK.sql Does not exist
    at com.eventdetector.utils.Utils$.getQueryFromFile(Utils.scala:19)
    at com.eventdetector.budget.BudgetCheckTest$$anonfun$5.apply(BudgetCheckTest.scala:47)
```

This file was definitely present in `src/main/resources`. Then I thought since I'm running a test case file from `src/test/scala` directory, I tried placing the file in `src/test/resources` as well, but that didnt help either.

EDIT: My `pom.xml` looks like this if it helps:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.eventdetector</groupId>
    <artifactId>EventDetector</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <inceptionYear>2020</inceptionYear>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <scala.version>2.11.12</scala.version>
        <scala.compat.version>2.11</scala.compat.version>
        <spark.version>2.4.4</spark.version>
        <spec2.version>4.2.0</spec2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
            <version>db2jcc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalaj-http_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
            <artifactId>play-json_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalikejdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalikejdbc_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/scala</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.sql</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.sql</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                                <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                            </args>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Tests will be run with scalatest-maven-plugin instead -->
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                    <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                    <filereports>TestSuiteReport.txt</filereports>
                    <!-- Comma separated list of JUnit test class names to execute -->
                    <jUnitClasses>samples.AppTest</jUnitClasses>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: did you call `maven clean` after changes?

Comment: I tried place sql script to `src/test/resources` and made `maven clean` and `maven test` and maven found it.

Answer (score 0):

While you are using maven convention, you [explicitly overriden it in POM](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html) to use different resource directories

```
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/scala</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.sql</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.sql</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

so either remove that section, or fix it to use `src/main/resources`.

Comment: I changed the directory references in both places as `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources` but that didnt help

Answer (score 0):

try add resource `src/main/resources` to resources block in pom.xml:

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <includes>
        <include>*.sql</include>
    </includes>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
```

in your pom.xml resources should be placed in `src/main/scala` and `src/main/java` but usually these directories are for code not for some recourse files. By default resources placed in `src/main/resources`. Don't forget call `maven clean` before testing.